# How can I create popup form in Yii2

Tags: ajax, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I want a way to create popup form when I press the button using Ajax and bootstrap

and how to create modal for it with bootstrap

```
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like it, call a view/action in modal

```
        <?php
            Modal::begin([
                'toggleButton' => [
                    'label' => '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success'
                ],
                'closeButton' => [
                  'label' => 'Close',
                  'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right',
                ],
                'size' => 'modal-lg',
            ]);

            $myModel = new \frontend\models\SomeModel;
            echo $this->render('/someview/create', ['model' => $myModel]);
            Modal::end();
        ?>
```

reference [Render Form in popup via AJAX](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/806/render-form-in-popup-via-ajax-create-and-update-with-ajax-validation-also-load-any-page-via-ajax-yii-2-0-2-3)